# Aggregating Raw data based on multi level hierarchy in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I’m relatively new to power BI and attempting to make visualizations to show data aggregated based on a hierarchy.

My 1st table shows the account hierarchy with the following fields.

| Name | Parent | Level | Level 3 | Level 2 | Level 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A_1000 | Cash | 3 |  | Cash | Asset |
| A_1001 | Cash | 3 |  | Cash | Asset |
| A_1004 | Non-Cash | 3 |  | Non-Cash | Asset |
| A_1005 | Non Cash | 3 |  | Non-Cash | Asset |
| Non Cash | Asset | 2 |  |  | Asset |
| Cash | Asset | 2 |  |  | Asset |
| Asset |  | 1 |  |  |  |

The next table shows amounts based on the following

| Amount | Account | Dimension 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A_1000 | A1 |
| 150 | A_1000 | A2 |
| 200 | A_1001 | A1 |
| 250 | A_1001 | A2 |
| 300 | A_1004 | A1 |
| 350 | A_1004 | A2 |
| 400 | A_1005 | A1 |
| 450 | A_1005 | A2 |

What I am trying to do is create a measure in reports so that when I display a table with the names of Cash and Non Cash and apply a slicer to only show the A1 items I would get something like this

| Name | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Cash | 300 |
| Non-Cash | 700 |

Currently I am using the below DAX formula which can get me the results for both A1 and A2 for the Cash and Non-Cash but if I apply a slicer it no longer works.

LVL_2_Agg=

Var C =  SELECTEDVALUE(Table 1[Name])

RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Table 2[Amount]),

ALL(Table 1,PATHCONTAINS(Table 1[Level 2],c)

)

I'm trying to see what I would need to do in order to be able to use the slicer and still get results for Cash and Non-Cash and if I could then use the same formula but change PATHCONTAINS(Table 1[Level 2],c) to PATHCONTAINS(Table 1[Level 1] to get the asset # as well.

Any assistance would be appreciated and apologies if any formatting is off.

Comment: The first requirement is you need to provide your sample data. Then your expected output considering that sample data. Of course, the explanation is important, but only an explanation can make things harder for people who read your details.

Comment: Went ahead and updated the comment to make it more clear what I'm trying to accomplish and included mock data sources that were simplified.

Comment: Through which column your table 1 and 2 are joined?

Comment: Name and account, typically relationship is many to many but I simplified it for the example.

Comment: Your name column contains NUmber and String values where as the account column contains only numbers. How are you relating?

Comment: example updated, both columns are considered strings.